how can a certain keypress be ignored while using the python keyboard module?
I have a simple bit of code that launches random files then uses the keyboard module to do certain things to that file.
eg.
def my_exit():
    "exits"
def nextfile():
    "does the next thing"
def deletefile():
    "deletes the thing"

keyboard.add_hotkey("n", nextfile)
keyboard.add_hotkey("d", deletefile)
keyboard.add_hotkey("esc", my_exit)

for g in allfiles:
    while True:
        chosen = random.choice(allfiles)
        os.startfile(chosen)
        key = keyboard.read_key()

This works fine if all I do is press one of the hotkeys. But the issue is if I press a different key (eg. page down) to control the file that has opened, it wont react to the hotkeys - it's like the python script has lost its focus.

keyboard.read_key() waits until a key (any key) is pressed, then continues. Meaning that after you press any key, it will move on to the next iteration of the loop (open a new file at random and wait for another keypress).
Maybe this can get you started--this iterates through files sequentially and progresses to the next file when your "next" hotkey is pressed.
def my_exit():
    sys.exit()
def deletefile():
    "deletes the thing"

keyboard.add_hotkey("alt+d", deletefile)
keyboard.add_hotkey("esc", my_exit)

for g in allfiles:
    os.startfile(g)
    # block forever until user hits keys to go to next file or exits
    keyboard.wait("alt+n") # hotkey to go to the next file

I changed the delete command to ALT+D to allow you to type normal text without causing the script delete the file--but you can implement it however you want.
I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with random--if you want the behavior to be "open any file at random until the user quits", that would look like:
while True:
    chosen = random.choice(allfiles)
    os.startfile(chosen)
    keyboard.wait("alt+n") # hotkey to go to the next file

